# Accidentally deleted systemd-resolved.service file, now can't install anything

Tags: systemd

Due to a dumb guid (And myself dumb enough to follow it) I deleted the systemd-resolved.service file, no can't resolve any domains and can't install anything into my ubuntu machine... Can anybody help?

Comment: Edit your post to include the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`, please.

Comment: @muru Thanks for responding! Just checked it, the file is empty... I did not modify this file though

Comment: Does `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` show it's a link?

Comment: @muru You are right, it's a link: "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 ene 26 15:27 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf"... I checked /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf and it's also empty

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.